# Can Quantum Voting Machine replace Electronic Voting Machine (EVM) in future?

Tags: classical-computing, applications

Some countries like India are using standalone electronic voting machines (EVM) for elections. They are not interconnected, use no power cables (run on battery), no wireless cards and are secure because after every voter votes he can tally his vote by looking at a printed paper slip (on The Voter Verifiable Paper Audit Trail (VVPAT) Unit) which has his/her candidate and party symbol displayed for 7 seconds and no one can take this paper slips out of the machine. If an attack happens on the EVM machine then votes counted on the machine won't get tallied with manual paper slips.
Theoretically, we go for quantum voting because classical voting is based on Prime Factorization, Discrete Log Problem which can be broken by Shor's Algorithm. But can quantum voting machines (if developed) have any practical advantage over the EVM?

Comment: Relevant: [A simple quantum voting scheme with multi-qubit entanglement (Xue & Zhang, 2017)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-07976-1)